# Flutter firebase phone authentication - how to get auth token

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, flutter

In my app I have both email and phone authentication, when i sign in with email it gives me a long auth token that i can use to read and write the database, however when i sign in with the phone i only get a short token that does not seem to fulfill the auth token position as it does not read nor write into the database. any idea how i might be able to get the right auth token for a phone authentication?

```
  String phoneNo;
  String smsCode;
  String verificationId;
  String uid;

  Future<void> verifyPhone() async {
  final PhoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout autoRetrieve = (String verId) {
  this.verificationId = verId;
};

final PhoneCodeSent smsCodeSent = (String verId, [int forceCodeResend]) {
  this.verificationId = verId;
  smsCodeDialog(context).then((value) {
    print('Signed in');
  });
};

final PhoneVerificationCompleted verifiedSuccess = (FirebaseUser user) {
  print('verified');
};

final PhoneVerificationFailed veriFailed = (AuthException exception) {
  print('${exception.message}');
};

await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
    phoneNumber: this.phoneNo,
    codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: autoRetrieve,
    codeSent: smsCodeSent,
    timeout: const Duration(seconds: 5),
    verificationCompleted: verifiedSuccess,
    verificationFailed: veriFailed);
}

 Future<bool> smsCodeDialog(BuildContext context) {
return showDialog(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return new AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Enter sms Code'),
        content: TextField(
          onChanged: (value) {
            this.smsCode = value;
          },
        ),
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        actions: <Widget>[
          new FlatButton(
            child: Text('Done'),
            onPressed: () {
              FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((user) {
                if (user != null) {
                  setState(() {
                    this.uid = user.uid;
                  });
                  _submitForm(widget.model.authenticatePhone, 2);
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/');
                } else {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  signIn();
                }
              });
            },
          )
        ],
      );
    });
}

signIn() {
FirebaseAuth.instance
    .signInWithPhoneNumber(verificationId: verificationId, smsCode: smsCode)
    .then((user) {
  Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/');
}).catchError((e) {
  print(e);
});
}
```

email code:

```
 Future<Map<String, dynamic>> authenticate(
  String email, String password, String token,
  [AuthMode mode = AuthMode.Login]) async {
_isLoading = true;
notifyListeners();
final Map<String, dynamic> authData = {
  'email': email,
  'password': password,
  'returnSecureToken': true,
};
http.Response response;
if (mode == AuthMode.Login) {
  response = await http.post(
    'https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key=[API]',
    body: json.encode(authData),
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
  );
} else {
  response = await http.post(
      'https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser?key=[API]',
      body: json.encode(authData),
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
}

final Map<String, dynamic> responseData = json.decode(response.body);
bool hasError = true;
String message = 'Something went wrong!';
print(responseData);
if (responseData.containsKey('idToken')) {
  hasError = false;
  message = 'Authentication succeeded!';
  print(responseData['localId']);
  _authenticatedUser = User(
      id: responseData['localId'],
      email: email,
      token: responseData['idToken']);
  setAuthTimeout(int.parse(responseData['expiresIn']));
  _userSubject.add(true);

  addToken(token, _authenticatedUser.email);

  final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  final DateTime expiryTime =
      now.add(Duration(seconds: int.parse(responseData['expiresIn'])));
  final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setString('token', responseData['idToken']);
  prefs.setString('userEmail', email);
  prefs.setString('userId', responseData['localId']);
  prefs.setString('expiryTime', expiryTime.toIso8601String());
} else if (responseData['error']['message'] == 'EMAIL_NOT_FOUND') {
  message = 'This email was not found!';
} else if (responseData['error']['message'] == 'EMAIL_EXISTS') {
  message = 'This email already exists!';
} else if (responseData['error']['message'] == 'INVALID_PASSWORD') {
  message = 'This password is invalid!';
}
_isLoading = false;
notifyListeners();

return {
  'success': !hasError,
  'message': message,
};
}
```

writing to database:

```
http.Response responseToken;
  responseToken = await http.put(
      'https://app.firebaseio.com/tokens/${_authenticatedUser.id}/token.json?auth=${_authenticatedUser.token}',
      body: json.encode(token));
```

reading from database:

```
return http
    .get(
        'https://app.firebaseio.com/products.json?auth=${_authenticatedUser.token}')
```

Comment: You usually use the uid of current user to read and write to the database, not the auth token.

Comment: @dshukertjr that does not seem to work for me, the uid is only about 28 characters while the auth for the email is like 3-4 lines of characters and that seems to work not sure why

Comment: @dshukertjr i get this error when i try to write {error: Could not parse auth token.}

Comment: That is correct. That 28 character uid is what you are supposed to use. Can you post the code you're using for the email and password sign in and code of reading/writing to the database?

Comment: @dshukertjr i just added the codes, in email i am using the idToken to authenticate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signing in with firebase auth using email and password does not have to be so complicated. Just do this:

```
  FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: email,
    password: password
  );

  uid = user.uid;
```

And, reading and writing to the database should be done the firebase way, not the old style http way.

writing:

```
FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference("users/$uid").set("test");
```

reading:

```
final data = await FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference("users/$uid").once();
```

Comment: that is for email though, phone uid still does not work for authentication for me

Comment: it's the same uid. uid's are supposed to be about 28 characters long.

Comment: I understand that, its just i straight up wrote the uid instead of the ${_authenticatedUser.token} and it still would not write for me, keep getting {error: Could not parse auth token.} but if i hard code the email idToken it works perfectly fine

Comment: @DarwishAl-Neyadi I have edited my answer. Firebase is nothing like a regular server and there is a firebase plugin for everything you can do with it, so use those plugins instead of doing it with http stuff.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can help me with this or not, but the previous method i used to post things into firebase database would set a randomized id for each list i upload. for example it would be products/{random number generated id}/List but now all i get is products/List

Comment: yes, you can. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write
 This talks about the web, but flutter is the same.